# Bash Script - File Size

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script. I need a modification for safety.

my original bash script:

```
mv /home/script/backup /home/script/backup2
mysql -u user -ppassword -Ddatabase --batch --skip-column-names -e 'select id, url from videos where url like "%http%" limit 1' | 
while read id url

do youtube-dl -o "/home/script/uploads/$id.mp4" -f 18/17/22/mp4 "$url"
done

mysql -u user -ppassword -Ddatabase -e "UPDATE videos SET url=CONCAT(id,'.mp4') WHERE url LIKE '%http%' limit 1" ;

mysql -u user -ppassword -Ddatabase -e "UPDATE videos SET source_id='1' WHERE source_id in (3) limit 1";

mv /home/script/backup2 /home/script/backup

exit
```

I need this bash script:

```
mv /home/script/backup /home/script/backup2
mysql -u user -ppassword -Ddatabase --batch --skip-column-names -e 'select id, url from videos where url like "%http%" limit 1' | 
while read id url

do youtube-dl -o "/home/script/uploads/$id.mp4" -f 18/17/22/mp4 "$url"
done
```

here: I want to check the file size. if it is greater than 10 KB I want to run the following all commands.

```
mysql -u user -ppassword -Ddatabase -e "UPDATE videos SET url=CONCAT(id,'.mp4') WHERE url LIKE '%http%' limit 1" ;

mysql -u user -ppassword -Ddatabase -e "UPDATE videos SET source_id='1' WHERE source_id in (3) limit 1";

mv /home/script/backup2 /home/script/backup

exit
```

If less than 10 KB or not found a file,  I want to run only this command.

```
mv /home/script/backup2 /home/script/backup

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the file size in bytes you can use the `stat` program. For more information on this type `man stat` into the command line. `stat -c %s <file path>` will give an output of the file size in bytes which you should then be able to check.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what James said, another way to check the file size is using the `du` command.

```
du -h somefile.txt
```

result:

```
4,0K somefile.txt
```

To omit the filename you can issue

```
du -h somefile.txt | cut -f 1
```

result:

```
4,0K
```

Comment: You may wish to omit the `-h` (human readable) this will result in the number being given in K (but the K won't be printed), and you won't need to check and strip the units. `-h` will result in different units for larger files.